# How to debug Android App Eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse

Ok. So while this isnt a programming question. I wanted to know how do people debug apps? How do you view log cat, and where these exceptions are thrown etc? And do I need to run the app on the emulator to see all the stuff, or is there a way to view this after running the app on my phone(while not being connected to the computer)

Links to plugins and tips would be really helpful, as im gonna start work on my next game, and while the first one works fine, had a lot of problems while debugging.

Comment: Can you explain  how you're wanting an answer that a game developer could answer better? As it is now,  this question appears to be more general and better asked on  stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cord to connect what ever device you using to test your program with your computer.

You should see the log cat in place of the command prompt.  All thrown exceptions and null pointers will show up there and will include line numbers which are very helpful for debugging.

Also It is important to note that System.out.print will not show up in log cat unless you specify that you want it to in preferences.  Alternatively you can use System.err.print which will show up as orange text in your log cat.

Hope this helps.